Paclet won't install because "another Paclet operation is being performed by a different instance of the Wolfram Language"
I would like to install the package IGraphM on an auchlinux server. After downloading the IGraphM-0.6.5.paclet from https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM, I tried running PacletInstall["IGraphM-0.6.5.paclet"] but found the error message:

PacletInstall::lock:
The paclet installation cannot proceed at this time because another paclet
operation is being performed by a different instance of the Wolfram
Language. Try the operation again.

However, when I look up htop or ps -x, I do not find another Mathematica instance running in the background. What could the problem be, or what should I do to further diagnose the problem?
